# How to add text to a vertical line d3js

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to add text to a vertical line using d3. In principle the text is attached to the line but it is not showing. Any idea why? Here is my code and and image of the current state.[Code problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfe2Z.jpg)
Thanks in advance!

```
        var espanya = aggregatevalue(data)[0]['2015'];
        var svg = d3.select("#UnemploymentRate")
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("id", "chart")
                    .attr("width", w)
                    .attr("height", h);

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "espanya line")

        var lespanya = d3.select(".espanya.line")
                        .append("line")
                        .attr("class", "line")
                        .style("stroke-width", 2)
                        .style("stroke", "black")
                        .style("stroke-dasharray", ("3, 3"))
                        .style("fill", "none");

            lespanya.attr("x1", padding.left + widthScale(espanya))
                .attr("y1", heightScale(maximo))
                .attr("x2", padding.left + widthScale(espanya))
                .attr("y2", h - padding.bottom);

            lespanya.append("text")
                    .attr("x", 486.78)
                    .attr("y", 300)
                    .text("Spain Average unemployment");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not append that group to the line element. You can append both text and line to `.espanya`.

It has to be more or less like this,

```
    var svg = d3.select("#UnemploymentRate")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("id", "chart")
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height", h);

    var container = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "espanya")

    var lespanya = container
                    .append("line")
                    .attr("class", "line")
                    .style("stroke-width", 2)
                    .style("stroke", "black")
                    .style("stroke-dasharray", ("3, 3"))
                    .style("fill", "none");

    var text = container
                 .append("text")
                 .attr("x", 486.78)
                 .attr("y", 300)
                 .text("Spain Average unemployment");
```

Try this and provide a jsfiddle if it doesn't work.